# Haskell: Type (without boilerplate) for a heterogeneous list of String and/or [String]?

Tags: list, haskell, types, existential-type, heterogeneous

I would like to have a heterogeneous list of `String` and `[String]`, as such:

```
strs = ["h", ["x", "y"], "i", ["m", "n", "p"]]
```

I know I can do this with a custom data type:

```
data EitherOr t = StringS t | StringL [t]

eitherOrstrs :: [EitherOr String]
eitherOrstrs = [StringS "h", StringL ["x", "y"], StringS "i", StringL ["m", "n", "p"]]
```

But I'm curious as to whether this is possible without any boilerplate, as in `strs` above.

So far I've tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class Listable a where
  toListForm :: [String]

instance Listable String where
  toListForm s = [s]

instance Listable [String] where
  toListForm = id

strs :: forall a. Listable a => [a]
strs = ["h", ["x", "y"], "i", ["m", "n", "p"]]
```

But haven't yet found a working method:

```
The class method ‘toListForm’
mentions none of the type or kind variables of the class ‘Listable a’
When checking the class method: toListForm :: [String]
In the class declaration for ‘Listable’
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I'm curious though: why not just `[["h"], ["x", "y"], ["i"], ["m", "n", "p"]]`?

Comment: Essentially, for user-friendliness.  I wanted the user to have more than one option in expressing their config.  After a while, a lot of curiosity as to whether it could be done.

Comment: These "lists" are called *Trees*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work for arbitrarily nested lists of strings with a few extension tricks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

import GHC.Exts
import Data.String

data MyStringListThingy
    = String String
    | List [MyStringListThingy]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance IsString MyStringListThingy where
    fromString = String

instance IsList MyStringListThingy where
    type Item MyStringListThingy = MyStringListThingy
    fromList = List
    fromListN _ = List
    toList (String s) = [String s]
    toList (List ss) = ss

strs :: MyStringListThingy
strs = ["h", ["x", "y"], "i", ["m", "n", "p", ["q", ["r", "s"]]]]
```

You need at least GHC 7.8 for this though, possibly 7.10 (I haven't tested with 7.8).

This isn't precisely getting away without boilerplate, the compiler puts implicit function calls in front of each of those literals:

```
strs = fL [fS "h", fL [fS "x", fS "y"], fS "i", fL [fS "m", fS "n", fS "p", fL [fS "q", fL [fS "r", fS "s"]]]]
    where
        fL = fromList
        fS = fromString
```

Although without the `fL` and `fS` aliasing, I only did that so I wouldn't have to type so much.  It only feels boilerplate-free because the compiler puts those function calls in there for you, but you still will have the overhead of turning those values into `MyStringListThingy`.

You could probably get away with heterogeneous lists of numbers using this trick as well, since numeric literals are also polymorphic, which is what the `OverloadedStrings` and `OverloadedLists` extensions do for those literals as well.  By making a type that wraps lists and strings, then instances the requisite typeclasses you allow Haskell to cast from those literals to your custom type.  The `TypeFamilies` extension is necessary for the `IsList` instance only.  If you want to play with it in GHCi you'll have to enable all these extensions there as well, but it definitely works.

A more generic implementation would be

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

import GHC.Exts
import Data.String

data NestedList a
    = Item a
    | List [NestedList a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance IsList (NestedList a) where
    type Item (NestedList a) = NestedList a
    fromList = List
    fromListN _ = List
    toList (List xs) = xs
    toList item = [item]

instance IsString (NestedList String) where
    fromString = Item

instance Num a => Num (NestedList a) where
    fromInteger = Item . fromInteger
```

The `Num` instance doesn't implement everything it needs to, just enough to show off that this works

```
> [1, [2, 3]] :: NestedList Int
List [Item 1, List [Item 2, Item 3]]
```

I wouldn't recommend using this in real code, though.

Comment: I'm simultaneously impressed and disgusted.

Comment: @dfeuer You're not the only one... It makes it look like I'm writing Python instead.